# does pouchdb-authentication uses https for exchange and replication?

Tags: security, https, couchdb, pouchdb

according to [documentation of pouchdb-authentification](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication), all the operations are done over http.

```
    var db = new PouchDB('http://mysite:5984/mydb', {skipSetup: true});
db.login('batman', 'brucewayne').then(function (batman) {
  console.log("I'm Batman.");
  return db.logout();
});
```

does it use https under the hood, or is the username and password really going clair and readable over the wire mode over the wire ?

Answer (score 1):

Works very well (example https://emissionsystem.org)

You need to have your web server use https and configure couchdb for https as well. Both are pretty easy.

[couchdb instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48203146)

Also you probably want to block http access to couchdb with a firewall rule.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly setup your server with an SSL certificate and use PouchDB with https.

On their site when it says that PouchDB uses HTTP, it is referring to the protocol being used. This doesn't preclude the use of HTTPS.